# What are the cheap and safe alternatives to storing information in file?

Tags: database, file, caching, race-condition, acid

I have a tsv file storing some information on AWS S3, but because of concurrent uploads/downloads in a cluster environment, the final state of the file does not always remain as expected due to race conditions.

What are some easy and cheap alternatives to this?

The file size is around **150-200 KB**. Using a database or cache would not be cost-effective if we use a managed service.

**1. Any way to maintain consistency and do some kind of distributed locking.

2. Any cheap and safe alternatives to storing information in a file would also be very helpful.**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use S3 object locks. With S3 Object Lock, you can store objects using a write-once-read-many (WORM) model. You can use it to prevent an object from being deleted or overwritten for a fixed amount of time or indefinitely. Object Lock helps you meet regulatory requirements that require WORM storage, or simply add another layer of protection against object changes and deletion.

Object Lock provides two ways to manage object retention: retention periods and legal holds.

A retention period specifies a fixed period of time during which an object remains locked. During this period, your object is WORM-protected and can't be overwritten or deleted.
A legal hold provides the same protection as a retention period, but it has no expiration date. Instead, a legal hold remains in place until you explicitly remove it. Legal holds are independent from retention periods.
To use S3 Object Lock, follow these basic steps:

Create a new bucket with Object Lock enabled.
(Optional) Configure a default retention period for objects placed in the bucket.
Place the objects that you want to lock in the bucket.
Apply a retention period, a legal hold, or both, to the objects that you want to protect.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock.html

Also, You can try use DynamoDB. Amazon DynamoDB is a key-value and document database that delivers single-digit millisecond performance at any scale. It's a fully managed, multi-region, multi-active, durable database with built-in security, backup and restore, and in-memory caching for internet-scale applications. DynamoDB can handle more than 10 trillion requests per day and can support peaks of more than 20 million requests per second. https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/

DynamoDB also supports locking. DynamoDB supports mechanisms, like conditional writes, that are necessary for distributed locks. However, the AWS SDK doesn’t include the logic needed to actually implement distributed locks, so this is up to You to implement. There are several examples for that, you may find it here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/ And here: https://formidable.com/blog/2020/distributed-locking/